# How to construct the explicit solution of this boundary-value problem of the PDE of the first order

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to find the explicit solutions of this boundary value problem of the first order PDE
\begin{cases}\tag{1}
\text{PDE: } \frac{1}{4}(u_x)^2+u u_y=u(x,y),\quad y\neq \frac{x^2}{2},\\[2ex]
\text{boundary condition: }\quad  u(x,x^2/2)=x^2/2,\qquad x\neq 0.
\end{cases}
I have tried using **method of characteristics** (see Evans, PDE) as follows.  The first trivial solution $u(x,y)=y$ is easy to construct.  Then I want to find another one. Let $F=F(p_1,p_2,x,y,z)=p_1^2/4 +z p_2-z,$ and $p(0)=(p_1(0),p_2(0)).$  By the compatibility  condition I found another $p(0)=(2t,-1).$ Now the characteristic equations are
\begin{align*}
&\dot{x}(s)=p_1(s)/2, \dot{y}(s)=z(s), \dot{z}(s)=p_1^2(s)/2+z(s)p_2(s), \\
&\dot{p}_1(s)=(1-p_2(s))p_1(s),\dot{p}_2(s)=(1-p_2(s))p_2(s),\\
&x(0)=t, y(0)=t^2/2, z(0)=t^2/2, p_1(0)=2t,p_2(0)=-1.
\end{align*}
The solutions to these ODEs are
\begin{gather*}
x=x(s)=t(1-\ln(2-e^s)),\\
y=y(s)=t^2(2-e^s-2 \ln(2-e^s))/2,\\
z=z(s)=e^{2s}t^2/(2(2-e^s)),\\
p_1(s)=2t/(2e^{-s}-1), p_2(s)=1/(1-2e^{-s}).
\end{gather*}
At last, I have to solve for $s, t$ from
\begin{cases}\tag{2}
x=t(1-\ln(2-e^s)),\\[2ex]
y=t^2(2-e^s-2 \ln(2-e^s))/2,
\end{cases}
in order to construct the explicit solution $u=z(s(x,y),t(x,y))$ of problem (1). But it is nearly impossible for me to solve (2) for $s$ and $t,$ so that $s=s(x,y), t=t(x,y).$  Any ideas? Or is there any other methods to solve problem (1)?